# android kotlin fragment error: Unresolved reference: application

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Working with room database. I've made a class **UserApp.kt** to connect my Database to app. this class working good in **activity.kt**. But when I put the code inside **Fragment.kt** class, red line error showing under **application** text :

> Unresolved reference: application

UserApp.kt

```
import android.app.Application

class UserApp: Application() {

val db by lazy {
    UserDatabase.getInstance(this)
}

}
```

In activity the code like this:

```
val userDao = (application as UserApp).db.userDao()
getUsersFromRoom(userDao)
```

But in fragment the code like this:

[image: But in fragment the code like this:]

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue like this:

```
val db by lazy {
    UserDatabase.getInstance(requireContext())
}
val dao = db.categoryDao()
```